# How to Loop Wifi connect command while disconnected, until connected, in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, command-line, wifi

I read up on For loops but im not sure how to integrate an IF statement to make it look more like a WHILE statement.

Windows Task scheduler will pick up disconnect events and run my batch file.

While wifi disconnected from "GUHOA" SSID run the "netsh wlan connect name=GUHOA" command every 5 seconds until its connected then stop.

Any ideas?

This is what im building off of:

```
netsh interface show interface | find "Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection" /I /C
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
  netsh wlan connect name=GUHOA | echo Connecting to GUHOA 
) ELSE (
  echo Already connected 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `for` might not be the best solution here. Use a simple loop instead:

```
:loop
  netsh interface show interface | find "Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection" /I /C
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 goto :connected
  netsh wlan connect name=GUHOA | echo Connecting to GUHOA 
  timeout 5 >nul
goto :loop

:connected
echo I'm connected.
```

note: with `netsh ... | echo something`  you pipe the output of `netsh` to `echo`, so you won't see it (but maybe that's your intention)

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply! Thats not my intention, I wasn't aware. Thanks for the help. I can work off what you've given me.

Comment: Thank you, Great job! 
i only changed a little bit the second line to find just the Wifi SSID using wlan:
`netsh wlan show interfaces | find "WIFI_SSID" /I /C`
if it's not connected the SSID will not be found.